# Ui-bootstrap-modal with ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13 and bootstrap 3.3.2, angular 1.3.14 not working

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-formly

As mentioned in the title, the modal does not show up.
The content of the form is loaded via formly and the content of the template seems to load, but it only shows the modal very thin, with the overlay but not the content.

I have a main controller in which I have:

```
$scope.add = function(){
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/js/templates/popupAddCarForm.html',
            controller: 'FormsController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            backdrop: 'static',
            resolve: {
                formData: function(){
                    return {
                        fields: getFormFields(),
                        model: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

My html is like so:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="popupAddCarForm">
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Adauga masina</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="vm.addCarForm">
                <formly-form model="vm.formData.model" fields="vm.formData.fields">
                </formly-form>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" >Adauga</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my form controller like so:

```
davidintercar.controller('FormsController',
    function($modalInstance, formData) {
        var vm = this;
        //debugger;

        vm.formData = formData;
        vm.originalFields = angular.copy(vm.formData.fields);

    }
);
```

The result is like so:

[image: The modal is in the red square]

LATER EDIT:

In order to rid ourselfes of other doubts, here is the code from the demo:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($modalInstance, formData) {
var vm = this;
debugger;

// function assignment
vm.ok = ok;
vm.cancel = cancel;

// variable assignment
vm.formData = formData;
vm.originalFields = angular.copy(vm.formData.fields);

// function definition
function ok() {
  $modalInstance.close(vm.formData.model);
}

function cancel() {
  $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

});

Link: angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-bootstrap-modal

LATER, LATER EDIT:

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8wgL4t2oXsFFeLBKGGW8?p=preview

Folder Structure:

```
--app
----js
------controller
------services
------templates
------view
----app.js
intex.html
```

My popupAddCarForm.html is in the templates directory, but as you see in the plunker, it does not render my loaded content, even in the same directory although a separate template file.

Comment: Did you have a look at [the example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-bootstrap-modal) which does this?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's a combination of the versions:  http://jsbin.com/migico/1/edit?html,js,output.  Maybe make a Plunker, CodePen, JSBin or similar, reproducing the problem, so others can help to debug what's going on.

Comment: @jme11: Going to make a plunker right now

Comment: @jme11: Added Plunker

Comment: @Gabriel Do you want to use separate html file for the modal template or you want to use inline-template in script tag?

Comment: @Icycool: I would like to keep everything separate, but check my plunker and my later edit please.

Comment: @Gabriel I'm able to see the popup after removing script tag from popupAddCarForm.html - script tag is only needed when you are embedding the template in some other html, not needed if it's a file by itself

Comment: @Icycool: Thanks, this was getting frustrating after two days of searching. Edit your answer, please add a link to where in the docs this is mentioned and I'll vote your answer and accept it and even score it :)

Comment: @Gabriel It's fine, the answer is getting quite out of context now, the title suggests version mismatch, the question code shows you were using inline template. I'm happy that your problem is solved and all is well =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modal template don't need to have the modal and modal-dialog layer - they will be generated by bootstrap.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="popupAddCarForm.html">
    <div class="modal-header">test
        <h3 class="modal-title">Adauga masina</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="vm.addCarForm">
            <formly-form model="vm.formData.model" fields="vm.formData.fields">
            </formly-form>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" >Adauga</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/risujodete/1/edit?html,js,output) Note that you need to match your template id in templateUrl.